# What are they trying to get with "GET /public-projects"

Tags: robots.txt

I haven't even shared my website with anyone yet and I have already started seeing attempts to `GET /public-projects`. However, I couldn't get any information about it, what are they trying to get? The bots are from google, ahrefs, semrush, etc. Am I reading this wrong?

```
[25/Jan/2021:16:17:24 +0000] "GET /public-projects?sort=updated_asc HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/7.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)" "-"

[25/Jan/2021:16:18:04 +0000] "GET /public-projects/admin-theme/blob/3.1.3/Froala/html/sticky_toolbar/bottom_offset.html HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; SemrushBot/7~bl; +http://www.semrush.com/bot.html)" "-

[25/Jan/2021:16:21:08 +0000] "GET /public-projects/admin-theme/-/commits/8f94155872475917218e2498018afff70fac1df4/Angular_version/js/plugins/codemirror/mode/coffeescript/coffeescript.js HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0;) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; PetalBot;+https://aspiegel.com/petalbot)

[25/Jan/2021:16:15:05 +0000] "GET /public-projects/admin-theme/-/blob/2665d433e32439c5a8b5dca6ee68032bb3eedbc1/Froala/less/plugins/colors.less HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5X Build/MMB29P) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.113 Mobile Safari/537.36 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

Comment: Probably the web site of whoever had that IP address before you did.

Comment: oh, interesting. I googled that request and the first page was "https://gitlab.kickdigital.co.uk/" which took me to my website "hupreter.com". Should I do anything?

Comment: feel free to create an answer